# Can I hide the mouse cursor in OpenBox?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openbox

I'm running OpenBox on a minimal Ubuntu Server install, the only way to interact with it is via remote sessions.

When Openbox starts up, there's a mouse cursor in the middle of the screen -- I have no need for that.

It doesn't mention anything on their [configuration wiki](http://openbox.org/wiki/Configuration).

**Does anyone know how I can hide the mouse cursor in OpenBox?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install unclutter
unclutter -display 0:0 -noevents -grab
```

Comment: Thanks, Dean. This is what I was just looking for. ;)

Answer (score 5):

Consider using `startx` with an `-nocursor` parameter

Like this:

```
startx -- -nocursor
```

I was using it to hide/disable the mouse cursor on a Debian touchscreen Kiosk.

All credits go to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157134/how-to-hide-the-mouse-cursor).

Answer (score 0):

Installing a custom Theme with an invisible (or missing) cursor icon is an option...